# Loop anidado en python

Tags: python

Estoy intentando crear un bucle anidado para revisar una lista de palabras en una lista de textos, pero el loop no funciona como esperaba.

```
palabra=["cefalea", "hemicraneal", "días"]
hc="cefalea hemicraneal derecha de 4 días de evolución"
hc2="Hombre con cefalea y ganas de dormir"
texto=[hc,hc2]
n=2
m=1
contador=[0,0,0]
for i in range(0,n):
    for j in range(0,m):
        if texto[j].find(palabra[i]):
            contador[i]=1
            print(contador)
```

¿Alguna sugerencia?

Answer (score 2):

No estoy seguro de conocer la razón por la cual usas las variables `n` y `m`. Si tu variable `texto` es una lista de oraciones podrías simplemente iterar esa lista y contar las palabras por cada oración. Por otro lado, el médoto `str.find` va a retornar `-1` si no encuentra la palabra, por lo que tu sentencia `if` va a aumentar tu contador ya que `-1` es evaluado como un valor verdadero:

```
>>> valor = -1
>>> if valor:
...   print 'Verdadero'
... 
Verdadero
>>>
```

Antes que nada lo que haría sería juntar todo en un solo texto:

```
>>> hc="cefalea hemicraneal derecha de 4 días de evolución"
>>> hc2="Hombre con cefalea y ganas de dormir"
>>> texto = ' '.join([hc, hc2])
>>> print texto
cefalea hemicraneal derecha de 4 días de evolución Hombre con cefalea y ganas de dormir
```

Ahora, para contar podrías usar un diccionario:

```
>>> contador = {}
>>> for p in texto.split():
...     if p not in contador:
...         contador[p] = 0
...     contador[p] += 1
... 
>>> contador
{'hemicraneal': 1, 'dormir': 1, 'evoluci\xc3\xb3n': 1, 'de': 3, 'cefalea': 2, 'derecha': 1, 'ganas': 1, '4': 1, 'Hombre': 1, 'y': 1, 'con': 1, 'd\xc3\xadas': 1}
>>> contador.get('cefalea', 0)
2
>>> contador.get('esternocleidomastoideo', 0)
0
```

También puedes usar la clase [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) de la librería `collections`:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> contador = Counter(texto.split())
>>> contador
Counter({'de': 3, 'cefalea': 2, 'hemicraneal': 1, 'dormir': 1, 'evoluci\xc3\xb3n': 1, 'derecha': 1, 'ganas': 1, '4': 1, 'Hombre': 1, 'y': 1, 'con': 1, 'd\xc3\xadas': 1})
>>> contador['cefalea']
2
>>> contador['esternocleidomastoideo']
0
```

Comment: Sin duda `collections.Counter` el la opcíón más simple y eficiente. Si se quiere reducir la salida a las palabras de tu lista basta con hacer algo como: `print({p:contador[p] for p in palabra})` con lo que obtienes `{'cefalea': 2, 'hemicraneal': 1, 'días': 1}` o incluso a una lista como se muestra en la pregunta : `[contador[p] for p in palabra]`

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta. La pega es que lo que quiero saber es qué palabras aparecen en cada uno de los textos y no el total. Supongo que con un tuple como dice Patricio podría resolverse. Saludos!

Answer (score 2):

En el código que publicaste veo algunos errores que paso a detallarte:

#### Problema con el [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#ranges)

En primer lugar ten en cuenta `list(range(0,1))` no te devuelve `[0,1]`, sino `[0]`, esto es por que la definición de está función es `class range(start, stop[, step])`, el parámetro `stop` no funciona como en otros lenguajes dónde lo esperable es indicar el valor "hasta", sino que es el valor dónde se detendrá esta función, es decir es un `< stop`, vale decir que cuando haces:

```
for i in range(0,n):
    for j in range(0,m):
```

Lo que logras es recorrer las listas hasta el anteúltimo elemento, en realidad lo correcto sería:

```
for i in range(0, n + 1):
    for j in range(0, m + 1):
```

#### Problemas derivados del uso del [`find`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=find#str.find)

Ya te lo comento **Cesar**, [`find`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=find#str.find) devuelve la posición dónde se encontró la cadena buscada y `-1` en caso de no haberlo hecho, y el `-1` en Python es evaluado como `Verdadero`, además si encuentra la cadena en la primer posición, como está va a ser 0, entonce el 0 se evalua como `False`, o sea nunca va a funcionar como lo esperas. Lo correcto si quieres utilizar [`find`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=find#str.find), sería hacerlo así: `if texto[j].find(palabra[i]) >= 0:`. Adicionalmente tal como comentaba hace apenas un rato **FJSevilla** esta función va a encontrar el valor buscado dentro de otras palabras, por ejemplo `"alcaldía".find("día")` se va a evaluar como Verdadero, con lo cual para el uso que le quieres dar no sirve. Es mejor buscar directamente por palabras, por lo que deberías hacer un [`split()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=split#str.split) de cada texto y hacer algo así: `if palabra[i] in texto[j].split()`

#### `contador`

No veo el sentido de esta variable tal como la estas completando, entiendo que lo que quieres es un contador final para cada una de las tres palabras, pero haciendo `contador[i]=1` no estás acumulando y por el orden de los ciclos tampoco puedo deducir que buscas un contador de palabras por cada texto. En caso que busques un contador total deberías acumular haciendo `contador[i]=contador[i]+1` o en su versión más acotada `contador[i]+=1`.

Con estas observaciones tu código quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```
palabra=["cefalea", "hemicraneal", "días"]
hc="cefalea hemicraneal derecha de 4 días de evolución"
hc2="Hombre con cefalea y ganas de dormir"
texto=[hc,hc2]
n=2
m=1
contador=[0,0,0]
for i in range(0,n+1):
    for j in range(0,m+1):
        if palabra[i] in texto[j].split():
            contador[i]+=1
print(contador)
```

El retorno final será:

```
[2, 1, 1]
```

Este tipo de cosas en Python se suelen resolver de forma mucho más sencilla y se les suele decir "Pythonica". La respuesta de **Cesar** va en ese sentido y creo que el uso de `Counter` es la forma más óptima de resolverlo. Solo voy a agregar una más usando comprensión de listas, una técnica de Python que lo distingue como lenguaje:

```
palabra = ["cefalea", "hemicraneal", "días"]
hc = "cefalea hemicraneal derecha de 4 días de evolución"
hc2 = "Hombre con cefalea y ganas de dormir"
texto = [hc,hc2]

contador = [0, 0, 0]
for f in texto:
  contador =  [x + y for x, y in zip(contador, [1 if p in f.split() else 0 for p in palabra])]

print(contador)
```

Lo interesante es cuanta lógica se puede indicar en una sola línea, veamos:

`[1 if p in f.split() else 0 for p in palabra]` con esto devolvemos una lista dónde por cada palabras tendremos un 1 si fue encontrada en el texto o un 0 sino, es decir algo así `[1, 0, 0]` si solo hubiea encontrado `"cefalea"`. Habría que adaptarla si además queremos sumar las repeticiones en un mismo texto, pero por tu código entiendo que no buscas eso. lo siguente es `zip(contador, ...)`, [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html?highlight=zip#zip) arma tuplas con un item de cada una de las listas en orden, es decir si combinamos de esta forma `[1, 1, 0]` y `[1, 0, 0]` obtendremos `[(1, 1), (1, 0), (0, 0)]` , por lo que luego al hacer `[x + y for x, y in zip(...]` terminamos sumando los valores de cada tupla y acumulando sobre la lista `contador` la lista indicativa de los valores encontrados.

Comment: Buena respuesta Patricio, complementa muy bién la dada por César al centrarse en explicar los fallos del código original del OP. Solo para hacer explícitas dos cuestiones; para recorrer una lista de longitud no conocida por índices lo normal es hacer `for i in range(len(lista))`. Por otro lado, usar índices para recorrer un iterable debe restringirse a casos concretos (como la modificación del mismo durante la iteración).Se debe usar `for-in`, es mucho más eficiente y mucho más legible.Esto está implícito en ambas respuestas: `for p in palabra`  y no `for i in range(len(palabra)): palabra[i]`.

Comment: Gracias FJSevilla, totalmente de acuerdo con lo de evitar el uso del índices para recorrer los iterables, tan solo  por la legibilidad ganada es que deberíamos usar  el `for - in`, además siempre podemos hacer el uso del `enumerate` si necesitamos un índice. Saludos

Comment: Muchas gracias a todos por las respuestas, os habéis explicado de forma clara. Sin duda, ha sido de gran ayuda ¡Saludos!

Comment: Perdonad que os vuelva a preguntar, pero no me quedó clara una cosa, si quisiera que el contador me dijera qué palabras ha encontrado en cada texto, es decir, los resultados por separado de los textos para poder luego agruparlos en una tabla donde las columnas fueran las palabras encontradas y las filas fueran los textos, ¿qué tendría que modificar? Realmente en la respuesta de Patricio, parecía que si se retiraba la parte de [x + y for x, y in zip se podrían conseguir los resultados por texto, pero lo he probado y no lo he conseguido.

Comment: Daniel, para tener un contador como quieres por texto, al menos en mi respuesta esto `[1 if p in f.split() else 0 for p in palabra]` te devuelve justamente el contador de un texto en particular, lo que tienes que hacer es cargar dicho valor en un diccionario por cada texto. Saludos.